# Can a mobile application that is developed to work on Bluetooth technology be used on Bluetooth LE technology?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can a mobile application that is developed to work on Bluetooth technology be used on Bluetooth LE technology?

Or does the developer need to modify code to handle Bluetooth LE (Smart) signals, input, output etc. ?

EDIT

While i was asking this question i want to know

if i write a code piece, can i run it on BLE devices, also with BLE performance?

Is it possible, or not?

If a device can have both B and BLE then i have one more question:

Should we write code with different APIs for ordinary B and BLE?

Comment: What do you actually want to do?  Normally Classic or BTLE are applicable to different use cases.  There is some ground in the middle where you could use either but it really depends what you are looking to do what the best solution is.

Comment: @Ifor I asked the q because i do not have a ble mobile device yet, but i need to develop some app for ble. I hope i will have some ble mobile device after a while, but until i have a ble device i wonder if i can get some experience on bluetooth classic

Comment: But what do you want the mobile device to communicate with and with what sort of data????

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any phone that is doing BTLE but not classic Bluetooth as well.  So the application should still work but it will still just be using the classic Bluetooth portion of the hardware.

Of course from the sensor of other device your talking to point of view the situation may well be different as there are BTLE only sensors for example that may have a similar function to an old style Bluetooth sensor but they want be compatible.  E.g. some classic Heart Rate sensors and modern BTLE heart rate sensors.

Comment: Nice background, however this doesn't explicitly answer the question asked.

Comment: True reading it again I should say no and yes to strictly answer the questions.  The feel of what is being asked though is will an BT classic app work on an android device that says it is BTLE capable.

Comment: Hmm, I'd say they are rather asking what they need to do to work with BTLE signals.

Comment: Maybe they will clarify themselves.  signals I believe is ambiguous although I am not going to skim the spec to check that there is not a very exact specific meaning for the term.

Comment: Incorrect question, looks like  application is developed on Bluetooth classic as LE is added now, so LE uses UUID's, characteristics so classic application cannot be used on LE, need exact issue from @merveotesi

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to **only BLE devices**(LE profiles) , then you need to definitely modify code as profiles on LE devices are GATT based , unlike Bluetooth Classic.
You will need to implement GATT Client and GATT server in your code.